# How can I refer to sub-elements in a particular variable?

Tags: c++, casting

My problem is as follows: I have a 64 bit variable, of type `uint64_t` (so I know it's specified to be at least 64 bits wide).

I want to be able to refer to different parts of it, for example breaking it down into two `uint32_t`s, four `uint16_t`s or eight `uint8_t`s. Is there a standards compliant way to do it that doesn't rely on undefined behavior?

My approach is as follows:

```
class Buffer
{
  uint64_t m_64BitBuffer;

  public:
    uint64_t & R64() { return m_64BitBuffer; }
    uint32_t & R32(R32::Part part) { return *(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&m_64BitBuffer)+part); }
    uint16_t & R16(R16::Part part) { return *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&m_64BitBuffer)+part); }
    uint8_t & R8(R8::Part part) { return *(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&m_64BitBuffer)+part); }
};
```

Where `R32::Part`, `R16::Part` and `R8::Part` are `enum`s that define values between 0 and 1, 0 and 3 and 0 and 7 respectively.

I imagine this should be ok. There should be no issues with alignment, for example. I'd like to know if I'm breaking any rules, and if so, how to do this properly.

Comment: Andrei Alexandrescu's talk on `Writing Quick Code in C++, Quickly` which has a segment on bitfields may be of interest to you. Link is [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly)

Comment: Why do you [think you] need this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm writing a VM to study how assembly works. Processors have registers that can be accessed in different ways, such as referring to a whole 64 bit register, or different parts of it in 32, 16 or 8 bit chunks (in x86, that's rax for 64 bit, eax for 32 bits, ax for 16 bits and ah and al for the high and low 8 bits). In order to emulate this, I need to be able to refer to different parts of the same memory in which I'm keeping the register.

Answer (score 0):

Type-punning through a union is allowed by some compilers, so you could simply have the following anonymous union member:

```
union {
    uint64_t val;
    struct { uint32_t as32[2]; };
    struct { uint16_t as16[4]; };
    struct { uint8_t as8[8]; };
} u;
```

Access to each part is as easy as reading from the appropriate member.

Comment: Massive warning on this. You touched on it, but, honestly, don't spread misconceptions without a huge red alert. This particular one is really widespread!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could you add more to your comment? What is the misconception being spread by this answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [gcc Optimize Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type%2dpunning): "The practice of reading from a different union member than the one most recently written to (called "type-punning") is common. Even with `-fstring-aliasing`, type-punning is allowed, provided the memory is accessed through the union type. So, the above code works as expected."

Comment: @Barry: That's one compiler. This is a question about C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can't find any docs for Clang, but even with `-fstrict-aliasing`, this example compiles and does what I'd expect.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see your point. That's why I said "is allowed by some compilers", not "this is always true in C++"

Comment: While I know some compilers allow it, and it works (as much as my own example works, since they're essentially doing the same thing), my understanding from the language of the standard is that this is not standard compliant. "Undefined behavior" allows implementations to do whatever they want, and in this example they choose to do what you'd expect. I'm looking for the "right" way to do it, not just "whatever works".